# ¿Cómo comparar tiempos mayores al limite permitido por Time() en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, time

Tengo una tabla en MySQL con un campo de tipo `varchar`, en el cual mediante el uso de la función `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` guardo tiempos con el formato de H:M:S, por ejemplo '02:20:00', '23:00:00','150:00:00','1080:00:00'. Hasta aquí todo bien, el problema radica en que si quiero obtener los registros que sean mayores a '900:00:00', no me permite , ya que lo que estoy haciendo es convertir los campos de los tiempos a tipo `time` y este tipo de dato te permite sólo almacenar tiempos menores a '839:59:59', aquí un ejemplo de mi consulta:

`select * from mi_tabla where cast(campo_varchar_tiempo as time) > time( '900:00:00')`.

Si alguien me podrida ayudar con esto se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien para qué querrías hacer algo así, ¿nos cuentas tu problema completo? Tal vez encontremos una solución alternativa...

Comment: Gracias por contestar, lo que pasa ese campo de tipo Varchar guardo el tiempo de respuesta que tarda un usuario en responder un correo, este proceso lo genero aparte. Ahora en la pantalla principal de la aplicación hay un filtro llamado tiempo de respuesta, dentro de este filtro el admin puede configurar el rango de tiempo por el que el usuario puede buscar, por lo que cabe la posibilidad de que en algún momento el campo por el que se filtre pueda ser mayor al tiempo máximo permitido por MySQL.

Comment: La forma en que lo hago actualmente es como lo mostré arriba, convirtiendo el tiempo de respuesta de tipo varchar a time para poder hacer las comparaciones

Comment: Ahora si me pude ayudar o plantear el problema de otra manera, se lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo guardar el tiempo de respuesta del usuario en un INT y utilizar INTERVAL para localizar los rangos temporales que necesites. Como puedes comprobar, funciona por encima de ese límite de 900 horas que comentas y evitas todas esas conversiones:

```
SELECT NOW()+INTERVAL 2000*3600 SECOND;
```

Si quieres que miremos tu código, súbetelo a GitHub, compártelo conmigo y lo comentamos por un chat. Ya me cuentas qué tal.